# Is it ok to mix use different texture formats at the same time?

Tags: directx, textures

I am using the expensive R32G32B32A32Float format for some quality reason. In particular, I need to retrieve the result by un-doing the pre-multiply on the buffer. Now I want to do some optimization. Thus I wonder if there would be problem / hidden trap if I mix use textures in different formats. e.g. Use another lightweight texture format for non-transparent images.

Note:  I am not making games but some image processing stuff. While speed is not that much of a concern because of hardware acceleration which is already faster than doing that on CPU, GPU memory is quite limited. Thus I am here asking.

Comment: In Direct3D 10 or later, the shaders normally operates with 32-bit precision. As such, you can use pretty much any precision formats you want and the data will be read in at that precision, and processed at 32-bit. In Direct3D 9 or earlier, pixel shaders tended to run a lower precision.

Comment: Thanks. I am using DirectX 10. I will give it a try.

Comment: Just as an side: Unless your system requirements are exotic and include out-of-support versions of Windows, there's little to no value in using DirectX 10. Move to DirectX 11 instead which has many more supporting open source utilities. See [Migrating to Direct3D 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3d11-programming-guide-migrating).